# Update tkinter canvas image through other script running in mainloop

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, canvas

*Goal:*

I have two scripts, one for the tkinter gui and one that I run when pressing a tkinter button, that generates multiple images.
I want to update an tkinter image canvas on the run, after creating the image.

*Excpected Results:*

The tkinter canvas image should update in each iteration of the for loop in GraphGen.run()

*Actual Results:*

The initial canvas image just disappears, no other image is shown.

*What i tried so far:*

I found that I need to use .itemconfig(...), still not updating. Using .pack() right after makes no difference.
Can you show me some good ways to do that? Passing the canvas object already seems messy to me.

*Code for the tkinter gui class:*

```
class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1280x720")
        self.button = None
        self.gg = GraphGen()
        self.canvas = None
        self.img_on_canvas = None

    def build_gui(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=600, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.place(x=500, y=100)
        img = PhotoImage(file="1.png")
        self.img_on_canvas = self.canvas.create_image(1, 1, image=img, anchor='nw')
        self.button = Button(self.root, width=20, height=20, text='PRESS', command=self.button_function)
        self.button.place(x=100, y=100)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def button_function(self):
        self.gg.run(self.canvas, self.img_on_canvas)
```

*Code for the generating script:*

```
class GraphGen:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.arange(0, 10)
        self.y = None

    def run(self, image_canvas, image_on_canvas):
        for i in np.arange(1, 6):
            self.y = [np.sqrt(i*xc) / np.exp(i*xc - 1) for xc in self.x]
            plt.figure()
            plt.ylim(0, 1)
            plt.xlim(0, 10)
            plt.plot(self.x, self.y)
            plt.savefig(f"{i}.png")
            if image_canvas is not None:
                img = PhotoImage(file=f"{i}.png")
                image_canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, image=img)
                image_canvas.pack()
            else:
                plt.show()
```

*Edit:*

I already have one file of "1.png" to start with.